# java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation at weblogic

Tags: java, oracle11g, ejb

Recently I'm getting sql timeout exception in one stored procedure, one db function and in an insert query via ejb call. Each deals with the different table and there is no table lock as well. The stored procedure mentioned above takes 1 hour to process 17k records out of 1.3 million records. This can cause the database to hang or just the used tables in the stored procedure?? I could see the row lock contention for the above procedure query statements.

Despite improving the performance or removing the auto commit from the java application, I reckon the database server is not allowing the execution during the peak hours. Any thoughts?

Comment: You could look at the profile of the user you're connected as and any resource limit from that or from [Resource Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-resources-with-oracle-database-resource-manager.html#GUID-2BEF5482-CF97-4A85-BD90-9195E41E74EF). As we can't see into your DB you should be asking your DBA about this if you aren't sure really, rather than us.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the connection to the database, after the stored procedure has finished executing
will probably resolve this issue.